How to fetch all events from Google Calendar?
The way I proceed, that accessToken is fetched via refresh token.
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?refresh_token=1//05Xa...

The events, first page of events are fetched. At beginning no pageToken is used. In the returned data there is also a pageToken. I fetch again. The next result will have only nextSyncToken, I used that with https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/urcr7s1cb
The surprising that the calendar I am fetching has 3 item from 2024-06-11 I see in Google Calendar when I log in, but in the datas which are returned, only one 2024-06-11 item exist. What am I doing wrong?

Does this answer your question? How to fetch all calendar item from Google? How to use pageToken and syncToken?

Please, either remove your first question, or wait for an answer on it, but PLEASE do not repeat your question (with slightly other wordings...), better is to use EDIT, an improve your original question.

deleted the other

If you've received a pageToken in the response during the initial full synchronization, you can obtain the results of the next page using the following URL:
GET /calendars/primary/events?maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&pageToken=CiAKGjBpNDd2Nmp2Zml2cXRwYjBpOXA
Java Code Samples
References

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/pagination
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list


And If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged-in user, you should use "primary" as the parameter value, instead of inserting the Calendar Id.
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary
References

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/get#examples


If there's any part I missed or misunderstood in your question, please let me know in the comments.
Have a Good Day - kevin
